# iOS event when the application is tapped from home screen

Tags: ios, iphone

I am developing an iOS application and I need to catch the event when the application is opened by tapping the icon of the application at home screen.

Does anyone know what is the name of this event?

Thank you.

Comment: you mean applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions?

Comment: You need to read all about the app lifecycle in the "iOS App Programming Guide".

Answer (score 0):

Add observer in your class

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWillEnterInForeground) name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification object:nil];

- (void)applicationWillEnterInForeground
{
 NSLog(@"App enter in foreground");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the application delegate you can implement the following methods to catch up with this events:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```